# How to change height and width of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I got this code for a bookmarklet from another website ([dublins](https://dublins.glitch.me/)) but I wanted to modify it and change the height and width to 100% of the page. I would do it myself, but I don't know how to use javascript. Thanks!

```
javascript:var url = prompt('What site do you want to embed into '+__uv.$get(location).href+'?%27);var%20prefix%20=%20%27https://%27;%20if%20(url.substr(0,%20prefix.length)%20!==%20prefix)%20{%20url%20=%20prefix%20+%20url;%20}%20var%20ifra=document.createElement(%27iframe%27);ifra.src=url;ifra.setAttribute(%27height%27,%27770%27);ifra.setAttribute(%27width%27,%271365%27);void(document.body.appendChild(ifra));
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of new `iframe` is set by this.

```
ifra.setAttribute(%27height%27,%27770%27);ifra.setAttribute(%27width%27,%271365%27);
```

Decoding into normal JavaScript yields the following

```
ifra.setAttribute('height','770');
ifra.setAttribute('width','1365');
```

Here, the width and height are set with attributes, but attributes cannot specify a size based on the page size. Therefore, use CSS as follows.

```
ifra.style.height='100vh';
ifra.style.width='100vw';
```

Now all we need to do is put this back in the bookmarklet.
Replace the first part with the following.

```
ifra.style.height=%27100vh%27;ifra.style.width=%27100vw%27;
```

So, the complete bookmarklet is following.

```
javascript:var url = prompt('What site do you want to embed into '+__uv.$get(location).href+'?%27);var%20prefix%20=%20%27https://%27;%20if%20(url.substr(0,%20prefix.length)%20!==%20prefix)%20{%20url%20=%20prefix%20+%20url;%20}%20var%20ifra=document.createElement(%27iframe%27);ifra.src=url;ifra.style.height=%27100vh%27;ifra.style.width=%27100vw%27;void(document.body.appendChild(ifra));
```

But sorry that I have not tested it because your bookmarklet didn't work on my end.

Comment: So far it's working, but I just wanted to make sure I put it in the right place when you said the first part. Please give me a few more details. Thank you though, you've been a huge help!

Comment: I have added complete code. Please try it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can confirm, yes it does work!

Answer (score -1):

```html
<iframe style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that it needs to be ALL javascript. That's because bookmarklets are javascript code that you can run within a website, and you can't use HTML or CSS.

Comment: why 100px? And why red?

Comment: @ItagakiFumihiko Because they didn't specify what they want exactly